# Mcqs to highlight wrong and correct answer using vue.js and vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

How can I highlight the options one by one to show wrong or correct option. e.g. if a user selects the wrong option, it should turn red until user selects the right option, turning its color to green. I'm unable to create the component as shown in the image:

[image: Example Image]

```
question: {
    t: "Question title"
    a: "Option 1"
    b: "Option 2"
    c: "Option 3"
    d: "Option 4"
    ans: "b"
}
```

Comment: How are you keeping track of which item has been selected? I imagine you are storing that in a variable somewhere?

Comment: You can push the user selected options into an array, and use some logic to compare the question to the array to determine highlight color. If you can provide a codepen or jsfiddle with your attempt at producing this component would be happy to help troubleshoot.

Comment: @Cathy Ha Here is the code pen link: https://codepen.io/mubeenmazhar/pen/pMRBZW

Answer (score 0):

Working codepen here: https://codepen.io/CodingDeer/pen/rXmNdO

1. I restructured your data slightly to be able to make vue loop through the options. This is not necessary but I think better than having to hard code the options.

```
items: [
      {
        t: 'Title',
        options: {
          a: 'Opt 1',
          b: 'Opt 2',
          c: 'Opt 3',
          d: 'Opt 4'
        },
        ans: 'c'
      },
    ]
```

2. Add dynamic classes to color the background of the options depending on whether it was the correct answer. Here I also disable the list items if the correct answer is chosen. It's an easy way to prevent people from clicking again.

```
      <v-list>
        <v-list-item-group>
          <v-list-item 
            v-for="(option, key) in item.options"
            :class="{'incorrect': userInput.indexOf(key) != -1 && key != item.ans, 
                     'correct': userInput.indexOf(key) != -1 && key == item.ans}"
            :disabled="userInput.indexOf(item.ans) != -1"
            @click="addOption(key, item.ans)">
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title v-text="option">
              </v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list-item-group>
      </v-list>
```

3. The javascript! Keep a list of clicked options by the user. Whenever a user clicks an option, if it doesn't already exist in the list, add it to the list. If the option is the answer, clear the list and then add the answer option into the list. Note that **you need to put each question group into a component** for this to work.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    items: [
      {
        t: 'Title',
        options: {
          a: 'Opt 1',
          b: 'Opt 2',
          c: 'Opt 3',
          d: 'Opt 4'
        },
        ans: 'c'
      },
    ],
    userInput: [],
  }),
  methods: {
    addOption(selected, ans) {
      if (selected == ans) {
        this.userInput.length = 0;
        this.userInput.push(selected);
      } else {
        const index = this.userInput.indexOf(selected);
        if (index == -1) {
          this.userInput.push(selected);
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```